# Find functions using temp tables where NVARCHAR limit does not match its referenced table definition

Tags: sql-server

Problem: Junior SQL dev here, working with a SQL Server database where we have many functions that use temp tables to pull data from various tables to populate Crystal reports etc. We had an issue where a user action in our client caused a string to overflow the defined `NVARCHAR(100)` character limit of the column. As a quick fix, one of our seniors decided on a schema change to set the column definition to `NVARCHAR(255)`, instead of fixing the issue of the the string getting too long. Now, we have lots of these table based functions that are using temp tables referencing the column in question but the temp table variable is defined as 100 instead of 255.

Question: Is there an easy way to find and update all of these functions? Some functions might not reference the table/column in question at all, but some heavily rely on this data to feed reports etc. I know I can right click a table and select "View Dependencies" in SQL Server Management Studio, but this seems very tedious to have to go through all of them and then update our master schema before deploying it to all customers.

I thought about a find and replace if there is a way to script or export the functions but I fear a problem I will run into is one variable in one function might be declared as `TransItemDescription NVARCHAR(100)` and one might be `TransItemDesc NVARCHAR (100)`. I've heard of people avoiding temp tables maybe because of these issues so maybe there is just bad database design here?

Thus far I've been going through them one at a time using "View Dependencies" in SSMS.

Comment: No easy way unfortunately.

Comment: SQL server has a few system DMVs that could help here for example `sys.sql_expression_dependencies`

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution would be to script out the whole database into a single script from SSMS.  Then use Notepad++ (or equivalent) to either find:

1. All occurrences of NVARCHAR(100)
2. All occurrences of the variable name, e.g. TransItemDescription, TransItemDesc.

Once you have found all occurrences then make a list of all of the functions to be fixed.  Then you would still need to do a manual fix to all functions, but once complete the issue should be totally resolved.

Comment: That seems to be the most logical solution I have to come to as well thus far. Thank you.